# I am installing pyautogui package and it is giving some Installing build dependencies ... error

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have successfully installed every other package, but nothing working for the `pyautogui` package. My Python version is 3.11, `pip` version is 23.3.1, `setuptools` version is 68.2.2.

I tried using the below commands to install:

```
pip install pywinauto --proxy=http://dummyproxy1.hella.com:2584
pip install pyautogui -i https://pypi.org/simple --proxy=http://dummyproxy.hella.com:7894
pip install --proxy=http://dummyproxy.hella.com:8785 pyautogui
```

As you can see below it successfully downloaded the package but got an error during installation of build dependencies. This is not a proxy issue or firewall issue as it already worked for other packages and I got the proxy from IT from my company.

This error originates from a subprocess and is likely not a problem with Pip:

```
PS C:\dev\git_repo\projects\megamax_test_automation_chrome> pip install --proxy=http://dummyproxy.hella.com:8796 pyautogui    
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.54.tar.gz (61 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConne
ction object at 0x000002365438DD10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConne
ction object at 0x0000023654239AD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConne
ction object at 0x000002365438FB90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConne
ction object at 0x000002365437E790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConne
ction object at 0x000002365437DF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
      [end of output]
```

This error originates from a `subprocess`, and is likely not a problem with Pip:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: From the error message, I'm assuming you're on Windows? What version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the http://dummyproxy.hella.com:8796 proxy is down or unreachable. Is this a real proxy or an example name you got from documentation? Also, it looks like you're using a different domain for pywinauto: http://dummyproxy1.hella.com:2584

I'd double check that the proxy is working, because the error message seems to be giving network errors about not being able to connect to it (and retrying several times).